# Avoid repetitive, similar analysis and plots

Tags: r

I have a table with many variables. One of the variables contains year information: from 1999 till 2010.
I need to do for each year the same analysis, for instance, to plot a graph, a histogram, etc.
Currently, I subset the data so that each year goes into a data frame(table) and I do the analysis in turn for each year. This is very inefficient:

```
dates <- (sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2010/01/01'), by="day"), 50, replace = TRUE))
dt<-data.table( YEAR = format.Date(dates,"%Y"),
                Var1=sample(0:100, 50, rep=TRUE),
                Var2 =sample(0:500, 50, rep=TRUE)

)
year_1999<-dt[YEAR=="1999"]
plot_1999<- ggplot(year_1999, aes (x=Var1))+ 
  geom_line(aes(y=Var2), size=1, color="blue") +
  labs(y="V2", x="V1", title="Year 1999")

plot_1999
```

How can I better write this in a compact way? I suppose I need a function but I have no idea how to.

Comment: Instead of doing this on each 'YEAR', you can specify the `group` as 'YEAR'

Answer (score 4):

Instead of repeating the code several times, we can specify the 'YEAR' in `facet_wrap`

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(dt, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) + 
    geom_line(aes(size = 1, color = "blue")) + 
    labs(y = "V2", x = "V1") + 
    facet_wrap(~ YEAR)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you want to create a separate plot object for each unique year in dt$YEAR:

```
for (i in unique(dt$YEAR)) {

 year <- dt[YEAR==i]

  plot <- ggplot(year, aes (x=Var1))+ 
    geom_line(aes(y=Var2), size=1, color="blue") +
    labs(y="V2", x="V1", title="Year 1999")

  assign(paste("plot", i, sep=""), plot)
}
```